# Implementing a saved ghost for each level in a game

Tags: iphone, algorithm, data-structures

I'm developing a video game for the iPhone.  I want each level to save a "ghost" of the best run, just like in Mario Kart.

I've already implemented it, but I used a brute force approach that stores (x, y, rotation) values each frame (60 per second).  Needless to say this is very expensive, especially for a mobile device.

I guess I could store the data less often and interpolate when rendering the ghost, but I'm not 100% sure how to do this and if it will look good.

Has anyone done this before?  How would you implement it?  Is there a standard approach?

Comment: Maybe it's easier to save user input instead of game data?

Comment: Only if there are no objects whose trajectories are dependent on generated pseudorandom values.

Comment: Why did you delete it?  I was still thinking about the different options...

Comment: For anyone googling this old QA, the answer below is totally incorrect.  (You simply, of course, store the position/rotations.  Even at 100hz it only amounts to *a few KB* (!) per ghost race. It's an absolutely trivial use of resources, so low it can't be measured.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear interpolation is very easy, if that's what you want. But if the objects you want to interpolate can have non-linear trajectories (from ballistic or lateral accelleration effects) the thing gets more complicated.

The simplest approach would be for you to record the initial position for an object and its movement vector (x,y,z speed, as offsets per time unit). You won't have to record it again for that object until it changes its speed and/or its direction. Then you just record the elapsed time, the new position and the new movement vector (theoretically you don't have to record the position again, just the vectors, but I'd recommend doing so to have a check value - after the program is debugged you can discard it).
Then to playback you place the object at the original position and, for each time frame, add the movement offset to it until it reaches the time for the next recorded position. And so on.

Comment: Hi Fabio -- you would never in a million years try to interpolate the data.  You would never in a million years try to "rebuild" the data from input or whatever.

Comment: Well, I didn't assume his program is like Mario Kart, I understood that simply the problem he had was similar to that situation in Mario Kart. Without detailed knowledge of his software I considered better to answer what he asked than make suggestions about his architecture. Your approach may be better for his specific problem, but he is the only one to judge.

Comment: Also I didn't understand why such rejection for storing object trajectories instead of their position. That's a common approach when you want to reduce the storage space. I have done that many times (not for games, which is not what I do, but for GIS systems) without problems.

Comment: OK, it's a valid point, assuming his game is that complex. Since he considered the option of interpolation, I assumed it wasn't (therefore I restricted the validity of what I said only to linear interpolation), and that was what determined my answer. Again, I have no idea about the complexity of what he's doing, so I tried just to answer what was asked.